# NSPointerArray/NSHashTable vs a weak wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-management

I know `NSHashTable` acts like a set and `NSPointArray` like an array, but what's better to use if one needs an array of weakly referenced objects, one of these, or an array of `weak` wrappers, like below?

```
final class Weak<T> {

    weak var value: T?

    init(_ value: T?) {
       self.value = value
    }

}
```

Any particular advantages or downsides? For example an `NSPointerArray` can not be specialized, but an array of `Weak<T>` can; so can `NSHashTable`, but it's unordered, etc.

My use case is adding view controllers to a broadcaster. They need to be kept as weak references so they can be deallocated when popped. So far I used both `NSHashTable` and `NSPointerArray` for this, both with success, but I'd like to be better informed when picking one over the other two.

The question was initially written in a generic way, because I'd also like to know more about this in a general way (when needing an array with weakly referenced objects), not only for my use case.

Comment: Better to use for what purpose?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of an array of weakly referenced objects.

Comment: Still, you should clarify at least your use case, otherwise it's quite a generic question.

Comment: That was the idea, to be generic, so I can learn more about the advantages and disadvantages of each, and make better informed decisions in the future, but I did add my use case to the question.